# How to use AWS IoT message payload in Rule Engine expression to generate PartitionKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, expression, partitioning, amazon-kinesis, aws-iot

Problem context:
AWS IoT connected to Kinesis Data Stream (KDS) usin AWS Rule Engine, there is an option for PartitionKey in Rule Engine rule definition. PartionKey could be popluated using an expression such as "${topic()}". Example message payload is

```
{
    Id:"123"
    GS:"123"
}
```

Question:
How an expression could be defined which uses payload, something like "part${payload().GS}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [substitution template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-substitution-templates.html).

e.g.:

```
{
    "rule": {
        "sql": "SELECT * FROM 'some/topic'", 
        "ruleDisabled": false, 
        "actions": [{
            "kinesis": {
                "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/aws_iot_kinesis", 
                "streamName": "my_kinesis_stream", 
                "partitionKey": "${GS}"
            }
        }], 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I combine it? something like  "partitionKey": "Part(${GS}/2)" to generate something like "Part1"?

Comment: Looking at the operators (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-operators.html) I that would be "\"Part\"+(${GS}/2)". Remember all that partition keys do is guaranteed distribution and order in shards.